# scroll not firing on UL?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Will someone help me understand why the scroll event doesn't fire in my sample? It is crucial to me.

https://jsfiddle.net/ioma8/tmpqf8Lv/

```
$(function(){
    $(document).on('scroll','.ulWithScroll',function(){
        alert('scrolling');
    });
})
```

Comment: Please add all the relevant information to your question.  At least, but not limited to, the extra details in the comments: "the `ul` is added dynamically" and "it's added via angular".   This would save all the "yes, but..." back-and-forth.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have an updated [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tmpqf8Lv/3/) that is working now.

```
        $(function(){
            $('.ulWithScroll').on('scroll',function(){
                alert('scrolling');
            });
        })
```

If dynamically generated ul you should target parent element that is in dom when the page is loaded
Check this updated [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tmpqf8Lv/9/)

Comment: Yes, thank you, this works. But my ul is dynamicaly generated. What do I do then? Why does the other way not work? Any solution?

Comment: This will work and in denamicaly generated ul because the .on() work with added dom elements after page is loaded.

Comment: Tried, you are right, in fiddle it works: https://jsfiddle.net/ioma8/tmpqf8Lv/4/ But not in my app. May it be because the UL in my app is generated by angular?

Comment: You should target the parent of that ul that is not generated dynamically. Try the code that i updated in the answer

Comment: As for your edit: this is what I do in my initial question; doesnt work thought cause of the not bubbling of scroll event as adviced in the other answer.

Comment: "Internally, .bind maps directly to .on in the current version of jQuery. (The same goes for .live.) So there is a tiny but practically insignificant performance hit if you use .bind instead.
However, .bind may be removed from future versions at any time. There is no reason to keep using .bind and every reason to prefer .on instead."
Used some other tricky solution for now, see the other answer comments.

Answer (score 0):

The scroll event does fire, but you cannot delegate it to the `document` or any other parent element. This is [because scroll events do not bubble](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/scroll).

So the correct way to handle the event is on the element itself:

```
$(function(){
    $('.ulWithScroll').on('scroll', function(){
        alert('scrolling');
    });
})
```

Comment: What if my ul is dynamicaly generated then? Btw thx for the explanation of not bubbing up. Didnt know.

Comment: If your `ul` is dynamically generated via code, then apply the event handler *after* adding the `ul`

Comment: Yes, but the ul is generated using angular and I am afraid I have no control over noticing when it is done. :(

Comment: Is this the only solution? https://jsfiddle.net/ioma8/tmpqf8Lv/6/
But this way the event is added many times to that ul.

Comment: Mm, fixed it this way for now. Works though doesn't look like a very neat solution to me: https://jsfiddle.net/ioma8/tmpqf8Lv/7/